# Unable To Add keywords to URL using URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing, url-rewrite-module

I am updating my question according to suggestion below

My .htaccess file code for rewrite -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^SearchResult/(.*)$ SearchResult.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

But above .htaccess rule is not changing my url . If you go to url below it is not rewriting url as per rule

Url - http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult.php?category_slug=t

Url Should be rewritten to 
http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult/t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: @TaZz
I don't think its duplicate . I have seen the link you provided and tried the solution over there but mine one is different thing . If you see my first rewrite rule i am already removing .php from url its xyz.com/SearchResult not searchresult.php 

so I need to make all links without php and also I want to Add Parameter to url like SearchResult/Keyword

Comment: url is here - http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult

Comment: Do you want `CategoryName` in URL to be passed as GET parameter with name as `category_slug` to `SearchResult.php`?

Comment: @anubhava, I want to convert SearchResult.php to SearchResult along with one single parameter

Comment: What its doing it - SearchResult/CategoryName

Comment: what it exactly doing is SearchResult/?Category=name

Comment: @steve Can you please come in disussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All Try the Code Below in your .htaccess file -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/SearchResult/$1   SearchResult.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    
</IfModule>
```

The code Above is for SearchResult.php Page For adding more pages you can undrestand and use similar type of code above like for About.php you can use below -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^/SearchResult/$1   SearchResult.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    

RewriteRule    ^/About/$1   About.php    [NC,L]    

</IfModule>
```

In You Case your urls will work as you need after above changesin .htaccess file . But your page css is fumbled after this as you js and specially your css files are not having root path try solution below -

**Convert following code lines**

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" async>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/alertify.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

**To Below**

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" async>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/js/alertify.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: @Steve ok and let me know if it helps you

Comment: ok thanks @Heemanshu Bhalla i think it is working let me test it completely

Comment: i think its working SearchResult/categoryname url rewritting now but on that page my css is not loaded . Can you suggest solution for that also

Comment: @Steve ok let me check it online

Comment: @Steve that's because your paths to css and js files are not correct that's why you errors in browser's console also

i am going to update my answer with updated paths to js and css especially css

Answer (score 0):

Order is important

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP

RewriteRule ^SearchResult/(.*)$ SearchResult.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#It is to check whether Request if for PHP File
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you see my first rewrite rule i am already removing .php from url its xyz.com/SearchResult not searchresult.php so I need to make all links without php and also I want to Add Parameter to url like SearchResult/Keyword

Comment: RewriteRule ^searchresult/(.*)$ searchresult.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L]

Use the above rule. Your url will look like:
http://domain.com/searchresult/pets

Comment: i am using RewriteRule ^SearchResult/(.*)$ SearchResult.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L] rule as you said but my resulting url is 
http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult.php?category_slug=234567

Comment: Resulting url should be: expertsusa.org/SearchResult/234567 

Post your .htacess file

Comment: my .htaccess file 
------# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^SearchResult/(.*)$ SearchResult.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>-----------
its saying too many redirects you can check online

Comment: you can check online here - http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult.php?category_slug=4 i will catch you up in 1 hr

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /SearchResult\.php\?category_slug=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /SearchResult/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^SearchResult/(.*)$ SearchResult.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: No its not working except homepage no other page is opening blank page on all other pages

Comment: Exact same rule in my Apache redirects `localhost/SearchResult.php?category_slug=t` to `localhost/SearchResult/t` Is that not what you expect? Make sure you don't have any rule other than what I've shown in answer and this is located in site root .htaccess.

Comment: Do you mean to put exactly as you given

Comment: it rewriting my url but throwing it on 404 not found page
http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult/5

Comment: I update .htacces with your rules you can see online - expertsusa.org but except homepage all pages are 404

Comment: So redirect rule is working fine but `http://expertsusa.org/SearchResult/t` is not loading correct content. Where is `SearchResult.php` located?

Comment: its in website folder . if i remove the rules it will work fine with searchresult.php and load result depending on values posted from back page

Comment: i think it is not finding any folder named t in SearchResult folder that's why its giving 404 but it should not do this

Comment: Is `SearchResult` name of a real directory? Can you add `ErrorDocument 404 default` at top of your .htaccess and retry

Comment: SearchResult is not a folder . SearchResult.php is file with SearchResult?Category_slug=t  that should be rewritting to SearchResult/t

going to add this line on top of .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107812/discussion-between-anubhava-and-steve).